# PHP Fatal error: Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found when trying to run test-sample

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to initialize php unit testing with my wordpress plugin using phpunit.  I am running xampp on windows.  My xampp installation is also on my E: drive if that makes any difference.  I am following along with this tutorial:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/automated-testing-wordpress-plugins-phpunit/

I have gotten to the part where I run

`install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root '' localhost latest`

I run that and it pops up and closes quickly, so I don't know if it is really working or not.  I then try to run

`phpunit tests/test-sample.php`

and I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\SRBC\tests\test-sample.php on line 11

Fatal error: Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\SRBC\tests\test-sample.php on line 11
```

I assume that means the install-wp-test.sh isn't installing correctly and it is missing those classes.  Any ideas?

Comment: I ran the bootstrap.php and it gave me this ```Could not find C:\Users\gaming\AppData\Local\Temp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php, have you run bin/install-wp-tests.sh ?```

Comment: From reading that tutorial it appears that `install-wp-tests.sh` is a UNIX shell script and thus won't work on Windows

Comment: Yes it didn't mention that in the tutorial link I posted, but it in the actual documentation of wp-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up needing to install SVN for windows.  Also had to add the mysqladmin.exe path to the PATH environment variable.  Then finally needed this :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249402/error-when-setting-up-phpunit-tests-with-wp-cli-scaffold

And after all that and 3 hours!  I got it to work correctly!

Hope this helps someone else.