# PHP Fatal error: Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found - phpunit

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit

I know that it already has answer in [PHP Fatal error: Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found when trying to run test-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763165/php-fatal-error-class-wp-unittestcase-not-found-when-trying-to-run-test-sampl) But it doesn't fixed my issue. I am trying to initialize `php unit testing` with my `wordpress plugin` using `phpunit`. I found this tutorial and it was easy to follow. Here's the link 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/automated-testing-wordpress-plugins-phpunit/

Everything was working great until the below step.

When I came to this Step in tutorial where the command  I tried to run

```
phpunit tests/test-sample.php
```

and I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found in PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found in /var/www/html/testwordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/tests/test-sample.php on line 11
```

I don't Know how to solve this issue. I found the same question in Stackoverflow. Here's the Link: 
[PHP Fatal error: Class 'WP_UnitTestCase' not found when trying to run test-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763165/php-fatal-error-class-wp-unittestcase-not-found-when-trying-to-run-test-sampl)
But it was in  windows. Somehow he managed to fix it. I checked his solution and it says that issue in MySQL.

But in my case, MySQL works fine and  I am in linux with the flavor of Ubuntu. Help me with some solutions to fix this problem in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Usually tests are executed after setting up Wordpress for that.

It's usually done by doing something like `bin/install-wp-tests.sh <db-name> <db-user> <db-pass> [db-host] [wp-version] [skip-database-creation]`.

It will replicate Wordpress in a temporary dir at `/tmp/wordpress` and some tests libs in `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib`.

**So, answering your question, `WP_UnitTestCase` is declared at `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/testcase.php`.** Note we are talking about `/tmp` and not some `wordpress-dir/tmp`.

If you are happy to have this class mapped in your IDE for development purposes, you can simply download the `tests` folder from [wordpress-develop repository](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/tree/trunk).

###### Recommended reading and references:

1. [Initialize the test environment locally](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/misc/plugin-unit-tests/#3-initialize-the-testing-environment-locally)